# How do you safely deploy api keys/secrets in python programs?

Tags: python, api, security

I am developing a python application that integrates a lot of APIs including Twitter, Reddit, etc. In order for my app to access these APIs I need to authenticate using my secret keys. Obviously, I can't distribute my keys in plaintext, nor can I distribute them hardcoded into my python files.

How am I supposed to safely authenticate my client to these APIs in a production scenario? Setting environmental vars is useful as a developer, but isn't a solution for a deployment. I am generating binary distributions using PyInstaller, but from what I can tell it doesn't do any obfuscating.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. I don't want to force my users to sign up for a Twitter Developer account just to use twitter integration.

Comment: you can't make it safe. Maybe if you would use some server to keep key/secret and program would send request to server which would use `key/secret` to generate `token` for other requests then it could be safe. OR you would have to convert program into web page - but this it would need to rewrite all code.

Comment: @furas so I would essentially have to build another program that generates the tokens for these APIs, then send those to the client? Can these tokens not be exploited like the secret key?

Further, how do android apps, etc, integrate these APIs securely? It's so confusing to me.

Comment: most APIs generate `token` which is valid only few hours. So if someone get this token then it can use it only short time. And if you really want safe app then create web page instead app. Android apps are created in Java or C/C++ which converted to bytes code or CPU code and is less readable and it is harder to find values.

Comment: @furas would there be any point to writing an encrypter/decrypter in another language and then use that to generate tokens locally?

Comment: It has no point. If you write in Java then you would have to also install Java SDK to run it. Better write all code in different code. OR create web page instead of desktop app.

Comment: I was considering bundling a native executable for Windows, Linux, and OSX with releases of my application that requests a token from a remote server. This way that part won't be open source (and obfuscated) and no one has to install additional runtimes.

My application doesn't make any sense as a web page, and re-writing it in a different language would massively multiply the difficulty of integrating all these apis together.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is to read your secrets from an external source like configuration file (see https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/configparser.html) or other binary structure.

Next, to protect your secret with some crypt, you can integrate a setup logic for your application.

Comment: I'm already reading secrets from an external file. My project is open-source so any logic can easily be reverse-engineered.

Comment: @CCD of course, I agree with you. Although the project is open source (or reverse engineered) what you have to protect is access to configuration data. I think there aren't other solutions.